# Why does 'npm doctor' produce permission errors?

Tags: npm

When I run `npm doctor` I get permission errors that I have not seen before:

```
Perms check on local bin folder     not ok  Check the permissions of files in /Users/Orome/node_modules/.bin
Perms check on global bin folder    not ok  Check the permissions of files in /usr/local/bin
```

I've made no changes that I'm aware of that would have caused this change.

What is causing this and what can I do about it?

---

Full output of `npm doctor`:

```
npm WARN checkFilesPermission error getting info for /Users/Orome/node_modules/.bin
npm ERR! checkFilesPermission Missing permissions on /usr/local/bin/.keepme (expect: executable)
Check                               Value   Recommendation/Notes
npm ping                            ok
npm -v                              ok      current: v7.0.10, latest: v6.14.8
node -v                             ok      current: v15.2.0, recommended: v15.2.0
npm config get registry             ok      using default registry (https://registry.npmjs.org/)
which git                           ok      /usr/local/bin/git
Perms check on cached files         ok
Perms check on local node_modules   ok
Perms check on global node_modules  ok
Perms check on local bin folder     not ok  Check the permissions of files in /Users/Orome/node_modules/.bin
Perms check on global bin folder    not ok  Check the permissions of files in /usr/local/bin
Verify cache contents               ok      verified 9656 tarballs

npm ERR! Some problems found. See above for recommendations.
```

Config:

```
macOS: 10.15.7-x86_64
CPU: quad-core 64-bit haswell
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 2.5.9-52-g8cffae8
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
Clang: 12.0 build 1200
Java: 1.8.0_172
CLT: 12.1.0.0.1.1602137645
Xcode: 12.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Homebrew and node can get out of sync and produce this error as a result. In any case simply

```
npm install -g npm
```

might take care of it.

If that fails, confirm that `.keepme` is empt and try

```
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/.keepme
```

Comment: For some reason, it does not help me. I get the following output:
```
up to date, audited 255 packages in 1s

11 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Comment: npm 7.6.0, macOS 11.2.2 - this does NOT fix this problem for me. Can't figure out what's causing this.

Comment: @luckman212 This no longer works for me either

Answer (score 6):

**Perms check on global bin folder:**
npm doctor is missing executable on /usr/local/bin/.keepme file

This solves the problem in my case:

```
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/.keepme
```

**Perms check on local bin folder:**
the node_modules/.bin folder is missing from the command execution location, you can create it manually or command:

```
mkdir node_modules && cd node_modules && mkdir .bin
```

Comment: i got this error, please help ***chmod: /usr/local/bin/.keepme: No such file or directory***, im using m1 macos

Answer (score 1):

In my case, after updating npm, I found that the `.bin` directory does not exist. You just need to create: `mkdir /Users/<username>/node_modules/.bin`

Comment: creating that .bin folder solves half of the problems on my machine, 
"npm ERR! checkFilesPermission Missing permissions on /usr/local/bin/.keepme (expect: executable)" error is still there, I guess I need to create that file as well if it doesn't exist