# Permission errors with 'npm doctor' following Big Sur 11.2 upgrade

Tags: npm, macos-big-sur

Since updating to Big Sur 11.2, when I run `npm doctor` I get:

```sh
npm WARN checkFilesPermission error getting info for /Users/Rax/node_modules/.bin
npm ERR! checkFilesPermission Missing permissions on /usr/local/bin/.keepme (expect: executable)
Check                               Value   Recommendation/Notes
npm ping                            ok
npm -v                              ok      current: v7.5.4, latest: v7.5.4
node -v                             ok      current: v15.8.0, recommended: v15.8.0
npm config get registry             ok      using default registry (https://registry.npmjs.org/)
which git                           ok      /usr/local/bin/git
Perms check on cached files         ok
Perms check on local node_modules   ok
Perms check on global node_modules  ok
Perms check on local bin folder     not ok  Check the permissions of files in /Users/Rax/node_modules/.bin
Perms check on global bin folder    not ok  Check the permissions of files in /usr/local/bin
Verify cache contents               ok      verified 10156 tarballs

npm ERR! Some problems found. See above for recommendations.
```

Solutions [that worked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64878148/656912) in the past for a similar problem do not work to fix this, and this appears to be a distinct problem related to Big Sur.

How do I correct these permission errors, or are they perhaps a known bug with `npm` on Big Sur 11.2?

---

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 3.0.1-74-g74fd6c8
CPU: quad-core 64-bit haswell
Clang: 12.0 build 1200
macOS: 11.2.1-x86_64
CLT: 12.0.32.27
Xcode: 12.4
npm: 7.5.4
node: v15.8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

See: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2856

However,

```
mkdir ~/node_modules/.bin
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/.keepme
```

Should resolve

```
npm WARN checkFilesPermission error getting info for /Users/Rax/node_modules/.bin
npm ERR! checkFilesPermission Missing permissions on /usr/local/bin/.keepme (expect: executable)
Perms check on local bin folder not ok  Check the permissions of files in /Users/Rax/node_modules/.bin
```