# Is chmod +x /usr/local/bin/.keepme safe?

Tags: npm, file-permissions

There [are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64808053/why-does-npm-doctor-produce-permission-errors) [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66244794/permission-errors-with-npm-doctor-following-big-sur-11-2-upgrade) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70454756/npm-on-m1-macos-mojave-global-bin-folder-permissions-error) here about `npm doctor` errors with Hombrew's `/usr/local/bin/.keepme` and the general consensus solution seems to be simply to

```sh
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/.keepme
```

Is this safe? Is there a reason not do do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think so. For what it's worth I tried this and both `npm doctor` and `brew doctor` are passing.