# npm on M1 macOS Mojave global bin folder permissions error

Tags: node.js, npm, homebrew

When I run npm doctor I get this output:

```
npm ERR! checkFilesPermission Missing permissions on /opt/homebrew/bin/.keepme (expect: executable)
Check                               Value   Recommendation/Notes
npm ping                            ok
npm -v                              ok      current: v8.3.0, latest: v8.3.0
node -v                             ok      current: v17.3.0, recommended: v17.3.0
npm config get registry             ok      using default registry (https://registry.npmjs.org/)
which git                           ok      /usr/bin/git
Perms check on cached files         ok
Perms check on local node_modules   ok
Perms check on global node_modules  ok
Perms check on local bin folder     ok
Perms check on global bin folder    not ok  Check the permissions of files in /opt/homebrew/bin
Verify cache contents               ok      verified 84 tarballs

npm ERR! Some problems found. See above for recommendations.
```

I can see there is a file called .keepme that is 0 bites. With these permissions: 100644

How can I resolve this? I have seen the [topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64808053/why-does-npm-doctor-produce-permission-errors) for the Intel Macs that have this same problem (but with the x86 install directory) but none of those solutions worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve this I just changed the permissions on the .keepme file to 100744